# Creating Monoids for every subclass using Scalaz (or Shapeless)

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless

Is it possible to create monoids for every sub-class? For example,

```
package currency 

final case class GBP[A: Monoid](amount: A)

object Implicits {
  implicit class CurrencyOps[A: Monoid](a: A) {
    def GBP = currency.GBP(a)
  }

  implicit def gbpMonoid[A: Monoid]: Monoid[GBP[A]] = new Monoid[GBP[A]] {
    override def zero =
      GBP(Monoid[A].zero)

    override def append(f1: GBP[A], f2: => GBP[A]): GBP[A] =
      GBP(Semigroup[A].append(f1.amount, f2.amount))
  }
}

test("GBP support plus") {
  1.GBP |+| 2.GBP shouldBe 3.GBP // passed
}
```

I would like to add more case classes representing *currency* (e.g `USD`, `EUR`, ..)

```
sealed trait Currency
final case class GBP[A: Monoid](amount: A) extends Currency
final case class USD[A: Monoid](amount: A) extends Currency
final case class EUR[A: Monoid](amount: A) extends Currency
```

As a result, I have to implement monoids for new case classes. It's somewhat boilerplate.

```
implicit class CurrencyOps[A: Monoid](a: A) {
  def GBP = currency.GBP(a)
  def EUR = currency.EUR(a)
  def USD = currency.USD(a)
}

implicit def gbpMonoid[A: Monoid]: Monoid[GBP[A]] = new Monoid[GBP[A]] {
  override def zero =
    GBP(Monoid[A].zero)

  override def append(f1: GBP[A], f2: => GBP[A]): GBP[A] =
    GBP(Semigroup[A].append(f1.amount, f2.amount))
}

implicit def usdMonoid[A: Monoid]: Monoid[USD[A]] = new Monoid[USD[A]] {
  override def zero =
    USD(Monoid[A].zero)

  override def append(f1: USD[A], f2: => USD[A]): USD[A] =
    USD(Semigroup[A].append(f1.amount, f2.amount))
}

implicit def eurMonoid[A: Monoid]: Monoid[EUR[A]] = new Monoid[EUR[A]] {
  override def zero =
    EUR(Monoid[A].zero)

  override def append(f1: EUR[A], f2: => EUR[A]): EUR[A] =
    EUR(Semigroup[A].append(f1.amount, f2.amount))
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Small suggestions

First I'd like to propose remove `Monoid` requirement from case classes, as they will carry implicit value in each `Currency` instance. Without this requirement your wrappers could be much more efficient and even implemented as [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html):

```
  sealed trait Currency extends Any
  final case class GBP[A](amount: A) extends AnyVal with Currency
  final case class USD[A](amount: A) extends AnyVal with Currency
  final case class EUR[A](amount: A) extends AnyVal with Currency
```

### Shapeless Implementation

From here you can build simple implementation via `shapeless` as required:

```
import scalaz._
import shapeless._

implicit def monoidCurrency[A, C[_] <: Currency]
(implicit monoid: Monoid[A], gen: Generic.Aux[C[A], A :: HNil]) =
  new Monoid[C[A]] {
    def zero: C[A] = gen.from(monoid.zero :: HNil)
    def append(f1: C[A], f2: => C[A]): C[A] = {
      val x = gen.to(f1).head
      val y = gen.to(f2).head
      gen.from(monoid.append(x, y) :: HNil)
    }
  }
```

and verify it

```
import scalaz.syntax.monoid._
import scalaz.std.anyVal._

println(2.USD |+| 3.USD) // USD(5)
```

### Further improvements

You can get rid of shapeless at all. Consider such implementations:

```
trait CurrencyUnit{
  def show(amounts: String) = s"$amounts $this"
}

final case class Currency[A, U <: CurrencyUnit](amount: A) extends AnyVal
```

`CurrencyUnit` now is not a matter of class, it's just compile-time type-tag

```
implicit case object GBP extends CurrencyUnit
implicit case object USD extends CurrencyUnit{
  override def show(amounts: String) = s"$$$amounts "
}
implicit case object EUR extends CurrencyUnit

implicit class CurrencyOps[A](a: A) {
  def GBP = Currency[A, GBP.type](a)
  def EUR = Currency[A, EUR.type](a)
  def USD = Currency[A, USD.type](a)
}
```

which you can configure for your needs

```
import scalaz.syntax.show._

implicit def currencyShow[A: Show, U <: CurrencyUnit](implicit unit: U) =
  new Show[Currency[A, U]] {
    override def shows(f: Currency[A, U]) = unit.show(f.amount.shows)
  }
```

And most important easily derive typeclasses via `scalaz.Isomorphism.Iso` functionality:

```
import Isomorphism._

implicit def currencyIso[A, U <: CurrencyUnit] = new (Currency[A, U] <=> A) {
  def to: (Currency[A, U]) => A = _.amount
  def from: (A) => Currency[A, U] = Currency[A, U]
}

implicit def currencyMonoid[A: Monoid, U <: CurrencyUnit] =
  new IsomorphismMonoid[Currency[A, U], A] {
    def G: Monoid[A] = implicitly
    def iso: Currency[A, U] <=> A = implicitly
  }
```

Finally you can verify this solution too

```
import scalaz.syntax.monoid._
import scalaz.std.anyVal._

println((2.USD |+| 3.USD).shows) // $5
```

Comment: Thanks @Odomontois. I had a hard time applying shapeless. Your answer  will be a great guide for shapeless newbies.

Comment: One more question, Why `GBP` should extends `AnyVal`?

Comment: To make a `value class` I think: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html